# Stuck on "Waiting for Ambari Agent to connect" HDP 2.6 Docker installation on linux

Tags: docker, ambari, hortonworks-sandbox

I want to deploy Hortonworks Sandbox on Docker.
My installation is stuck on :

> Waiting for ambari agent to connect
>   .......    "state" : "INSTALLED",

I looked into the start_sandbox_hdp.sh and found that installation is stuck on:

```
docker exec -t sandbox-hdp /bin/sh -c ' until curl --silent -u admin:password123 -H "X-Requested-By:ambari" -i -X GET http://localhost:8080/api/v1/clusters/Sandbox/hosts/sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com/host_components/ZOOKEEPER_SERVER | grep state | grep -v desired | grep INSTALLED; do sleep 5; echo -n .; done;'
```

Comment: Need more information. What instructions are you following? Where can we get `start_sandbox_hdp.sh` to test? What Docker version? How was Docker installed on the host? What OS is the host?

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hortonworks/data-tutorials/master/tutorials/hdp/sandbox-deployment-and-install-guide/assets/start_sandbox-hdp.sh

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem of docker's version. Uninstall the current version 17.12 and install the version 17.09. It should works now.